How to find out the value of +40 years old resistor?

Can anyone tell me the value of this resistor? Now, it is fried so it is not possible to read or measure it. The picture I show here is before the incident. Looks like orange-red-silver-gold which means 0.32 @ 5%, right?
Or could it be brown-orange-silver-gold, 0.13 @ 5%?
The board is 40+ years old so perhaps the colors are faded?
It's a power supply board from an old Allen organ and they don't publish schematics for anything.

More likely brown red silver gold

look for a resistor with the same colors and measure it

@jsotola Would have done so, but there is no other such resistor on that board.

@DonCaton Maybe try to guess some colors, like finding resistors with some of the same colors and trying to infer the numbers of the bands based on what you measured on other resistors. If not possible, find similar boards with similar components. K??

@tac Well, there are limited possibilities. The top band is either brown or orange, and the second band is either orange or red, and the third band is either white or silver. The possibilities are 12, 13 or 32. Orange-orange is not likely as the two bands are different, whatever they may be. Which leaves six possibilities: .012, .013, .032, 12G, 13G or 32G.

@tac There aren't any similar boards. This is from a 40+ year old church organ. Expensive, not mass produced, and most are out of service and in landfills by now.

@DonCaton Just try with different values till the organ works well.

Compare your resistor to the possible 5% resistor values(Google 'E24 resistor values').  I agree that your bottom two bands are silver, then gold (top to bottom), so it is a 5% resistor with 0.01 multiplier.
One source of E24 values:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_series_of_preferred_numbers
From there:
1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.5, 1.6, 1.8, 2.0, 2.2, 2.4, 2.7, 3.0, 3.3, 3.6, 3.9, 4.3, 4.7, 5.1, 5.6, 6.2, 6.8, 7.5, 8.2, 9.1
Now for the top 2 bands
2nd band from the top is red, possible values are 0.12,0.22,0.62,0.82.
2nd band from top is orange, possible values are 0.13,0.33.
Based on the colors, I'd go with 0.12 ohm. The other reasonable alternative is 0.13 ohm.
Another factor in deciding on those 2 possible values is the color of the ceramic cap to the left of the resistor.  I've always seen them as yellow, heading to brownish yellow, not orangish yellow.  The top band and that cap seem to be in the same range of colors, so I'm calling the top band brown.
Given that the circuit is using a 5% resistor, not a 2% or 1%, the circuit isn't THAT sensitive to the difference between 0.12 ohm and 0.13 ohm, or the designer would have used a more accurate resistor.

@JkiungNH Thank you for the detailed response, it's appreciated. I found some 5W 0.12 ohm resistors on Amazon so I'm going to give that a try, in addition to replacing the electrolytic caps.

If it doesn't work (for instance, because the resistor is burnt), measuring it is your best option;
The resistor might be a component of a building block that is duplicated elsewhere on the board.
Use your understanding of the surrounding circuitry to determine the working voltage and/or current, and measure the resistor's length and diameter to determine its packaging and power rating. The final value can then be found by using U = RI and P = RI².
https://eepower.com/resistor-guide/resistor-standards-and-codes/resistor-sizes-and-packages/#


Thanks. Unfortunately, my understanding of the surrounding circuitry is locked away somewhere in brain cells that haven't been used in 50 years, since I had classes in electronics. I ended up going into programming and forgot probably 90% of what I used to know when it comes to stuff like this.
